# firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.firestore is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

*I gets this error*
but when u hover mouse cursor on the .firestore() then in snippet it defines it as a function but on compilation/web it shows the following error.
*help me to solve it*

```
 **firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.firestore is not a function** 
  
  
  
  3 | import 'firebase/firestore';
  4 | 
  5 | import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
> 6 | const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  7 | const firebaseConfig = {
  8 |     apiKey: "--------",
  9 |     authDomain: "--------",
```

Comment: Does Jay Lu's answer solve your issue? If not, I'd ask that you provide more details about your case.

Answer (score 1):

The method you use is before version 9, if your are useing firebase v9.x.x, the method changed.

- Here is the [(v9) Firebase official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9).
- Here is the [(v8 or before) Firebase official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-8_1).

**Simple example :**

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxx"
};

const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

export { firebase, db };
```